# Get RibbonPageGroup names

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I want to get all Ribbon Page Group names from Ribbon Control. in Windows form application using c# .net #

i just try

```
foreach (RibbonPageGroup rpg in ribbonControl1.Pages)
{


 }
```

Comment: Is this a DevExpress component?

Comment: Yes it isDevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonControl ribbonControl1

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument2515

Comment: I want just get list of all RibbonPageGroup from RibbonControl at run time in load event

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RibbonPage.Groups` property to access `RibbonPageGroupCollection`
Try like this

```
foreach (RibbonPage page in ribbonControl1.Pages)
{ 
  foreach (RibbonPageGroup group in page.Groups)
  {
    group.Name//Gets the name of the current component.
    group.Text//Gets or sets the text displayed within the group.
  }
}
```

Reference : 
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonPageGroupMembersTopicAll
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonPageGroupCollectiontopic

Comment: yes it is work but now question is how to get ribbonpagegroup name where u write //your code here

Comment: @Yogipatel see the edited answer.go through the reference link.

Comment: see my edited answer.https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonPageGroup_Texttopic